# What is an alternative to win32gui in python 2.7 for mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7

I am using win32gui for figuring out that a specific window has been opened or not in Windows. I want to have same functionality in mac os also. 
In Windows
    import win32gui
    win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)

what is equivalent lib in python 2.7 for mac os?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution for above problem

```
from Quartz import CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo, kCGNullWindowID, kCGWindowListOptionAll
import datetime, time
print datetime.datetime.now()
found = False
count = 0
windowName = "Hello World"
while 1:
    list = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionAll, kCGNullWindowID)
time.sleep(0.2)
for a in list:
    try:
        if a['kCGWindowName'] == windowName:
            print "**** yippee *****"
            print "window found"
            print a
            found = True
            break
    except:
        pass
    if found == True:
        break
    print "NOT FOUND", count
    count+=1

print datetime.datetime.now()
```